# No network connection Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ethernet

I recently updated my PC to Windows 10 from Windows 8. My computer is not finding my ethernet network adapter anymore and I therefore lost internet connection. My motherboard is the MSI B85-G43 and the Network Card is the Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller. I updated to the latest driver from the MSI support site for the network card and it's showing in the Device Manager.

Note: In the device manager, in the Properties => "Events" tab of the card is an event: "failed to migrate device".

Does someone know how to fix it ?

Comment: Did you check if the driver you installed is for Windows 10 ?

Comment: Yes I took Windows 10 drivers on MSI website for this specific mobo. The strange thing is that the card is correctly recogized in the Device Manager but here is no Network Adapter in teh Network Center.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem in my mind is to uninstall completely all the drivers related to your ethernet device and then reinstalling them from [Realtek Website](http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

during upgrade from previous Windows versions, sometimes the device drivers get corrupted. In that state, it is even impossible to update them to newer versions. This is, in particular, a problem if software like Cisco VPN client or CommView was installed on the previous system.

A solution I found for that problem was uninstalling all drivers for the non-working device (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/948372/windows-10-no-connections-are-available/952347#952347)).