# Windows 10 no wireless connections available after latest update

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, windows-10

First off, I looked here at this [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/948372/windows-10-no-connections-are-available?newreg=c205c74b236a445ca13df5ca92b94b79), but there are several differences:

- I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 many months ago
- This happened before the reboot after the latest update
- I was in the middle of an iTunes installation (which I needed because iTunes mysteriously disappeared sometime over the last couple of days -- not the icon, the *program*)

While iTunes was being installed, a window popped up that said it was installing a driver. Since Windows had finished doing its thing prior to reboot and iTunes (I thought) didn't install drivers in separate windows, I just hit close, because as far as I knew, there were no drivers being installed.

A few minutes later, I couldn't get on the internet, and the bars down next to the time were grayed out with the x in a circle. No wireless connections available. I have to assume it was the driver installation that was happening out of nowhere.

I went to Network Settings, and Wi-Fi was turned off. I clicked on the oval to turn it on, it wouldn't turn on.

I deleted the wireless driver from Device Manager, since it will reinstall by default. I also tried a program from [DriveTheLife.com](http://www.drivethelife.com/windows-10/fix-no-wifi-available-after-windows-10-update.html), but you have to pay for it if you want to download any drivers from a connected computer to a disconnected computer. I am leery of such software, anyway...

Is there anything you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.

I had been going between two laptops, one of which required that you hold down the FN key to do what are supposed to be default actions, like F1 through F12. This is my work computer. I use a few of those keys fairly frequently, so when I went back to my computer and tried to rename a file, I hit FN + F2 to do that. Nothing happened, so I looked at the keys and remembered that I didn't have to hit FN to rename the file.

But FN + F2 is the toggle for wireless functions to be on or off. So... I had turned off wireless functionality.

I still don't know what driver was installing that I cancelled.

I'm writing this for any people who may have this problem in the future, since this is a question and answer site. I hope this helps.